# How to select all even id's from a Table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I want to select all even posts id's from a table in my MySQL db and then display them. I also want to get all posts with odd id's and display them somewhere else.

I want to do this with PHP since that is the server-side language I am using.

Alternatively, would I have to select all posts and then check if they are even/odd with JavaScript? I would prefer PHP, but if it works with JavaScript that would be fine too.

Example of what I want:

table:

```
==================================================
id | text
==================================================
==================================================
| 1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. |
================================================== 
| 2 | turpis quis aliquet commodo, urna quam viverra justo, in |
==================================================
| 3 | Etiam in lectus sem. Nullam molestie nisl vel nunc consectetur |
==================================================
| 4 | Vestibulum eu molestie sapien. Ut luctus nulla vel libero sagittis |
==================================================
```

my failed attempt at a table in stackoverflow ^^

I want to display the even ones first, and the odd ones second:

Even Rows:

---

turpis quis aliquet commodo, urna quam viverra justo, in

Vestibulum eu molestie sapien. Ut luctus nulla vel libero sagittis

---

Odd Rows:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

Etiam in lectus sem. Nullam molestie nisl vel nunc consectetur

Comment: order by MOD(ID,2), ID

Comment: This ^ is the right answer.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

To select even or odd IDs from a MySQL table, you would use the [modulo](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) operator (like in PHP):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id % 2) = 0; # even
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id % 2) > 0; # odd
```

Comment: Any idea on how to exclude 0 from even? so it only check 2,4,6,8 not(0)

Comment: @mediaroot sorry I didn't see this earlier: `WHERE (id % 2) = 0 AND id <> 0` (`<>` is the same as `!=`)

Answer (score 14):

In order to select even or odd IDs from a MySQL table, you would use the 'MOD', this easy way to select the Odd and Even numbers.

**Select Odd number**

```
select column_name from table_name where mod(column_name,2)=1;
```

**Select Even number**

```
select column_name from table_name where mod(column_name,2)=0;
```

if you need an Odd number, put 1.

if you need an Even number, put 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (id%2)=0;
```

this query returns the result for which ID is even number.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id&1 = 0
```

eg `5%2` takes more time to calculation, bitwise operators faster then Arithmetic

- *for 5*,  101 & 001 = 001 i.e 1 for odd
- *for 4*,  100 & 001 = 000 i.e 0 for even

`// for displaying even first then odd`

```
    
        id | text
        ---------
        1  | odd-1
        ---------
        2  | even-1
        ---------
        3  | odd-2
        --------
        4  | even-2
        ----------
        5  | odd-3
        ----------
```

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE order by id&1 asc;
```

Result

```
id text
--------

2  even-1
-----------
4  even-2
----------
1  odd-1
----------
3  odd-2
----------
5  odd-3
```

---