# Syntax SQL to return even number in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Query a list of CITY names from STATION for cities that have an even ID number. Print the results in any order, but exclude duplicates from the answer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
where id %2 = 0
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station where id like '%2'  
Try this and if it works I will mark up an answer with it.

Comment: Do you need ALL Even ID # ? You could run it just like that 5 more times with each even number and JOIN the lists together to have ALL Even IDs?

Comment: That being said .. it MIGHT be a duplicate of this question --
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505116/how-to-select-all-even-ids-from-a-table

Comment: Imagine that there exists 2 duplicates for some city, and one of them have even ID whereas another one have odd ID... does this city must be selected due to even ID presence, or backward, it must not be selected due to odd ID?

Comment: ```.. where id %2 = 0``` I'd prefer `.. WHERE NOT id MOD 2`.

Comment: Bitwise operations are always faster than arithmetical operations.  `WHERE !(id & 1)`.

Comment: @GeorgRichter The difference between these 3 variants is not detectable, because DISTINCT will eat the most part of data processing time, even when the whole table is already cached.

Answer (score 0):

In My SQL, might use MOD function.

Check this to find rows where a specified column has even values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE MOD(ID, 2) = 0
```